# Using Rule-based/Geometry generator style in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, rule-based, geometry-generator, layer-name

I have layer for comments in qgis, symbology style is  rule based with Geometry generator.

[image]

Problem is with displaying name in layers tab because the line before text is too long

[image]

How do I solve the problem so that the line was as short as on all other layers?

Comment: It looks like you're using geometry generator to create the leading line for the label, QGIS not has native support for leading lins within label settings, have you tried using this instead of the geometry generator?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question, i need that leading line, is there any other way to get same effekt with label.

Comment: Yes there is, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating the leading lines using geometry generator symbology, try using the Callouts tab in the Label options:

[image]

You can configure the leading lines with the options shown in the screenshot. It may take some configuring to make them look the same as they were in the geometry generator but doing it this way won't show up in the table of contents or legend.

Comment: Keep in mind this feature was added to QGIS 3.10. See https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog310/#feature-label-callouts. It is not available in previous versions like the current LTR 3.4.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem, yes I am using qgis 3.4 and didn't know about this great new feature in QGIS 3.10